# How do I delete a label off of the screen in a python Tk GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

```
#here is the example code:
label1 = Label(app, text="This is a Label!")
label1.pack()
#But when i do:
label1.pack_forget()
#I get this error:
#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack_forget'
#I also try:
label1.destroy()
```

I get the same error.
I want to be able to take the label off of the screen so i can
put an updated label on the screen.

Comment: The code in your question will not give the error you say it does. Does your actual code create the label like this: `label1=Label(...).pack(...)`?

Comment: Yes the actual code does make the label like that. this is an example of my problem. By the way I am running python 2.7.5 if that info helps, thanks.

Comment: Ok, so you're asking us to debug your code by showing us code that is _not_ your code. In the future, if you want  help, show us actual code that demonstrates the problem, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as explained in the comment section of the question, is that you're doing this:

```
label1=Label(...).pack(...)
```

That causes `label1` to be `None`. Whenever you do `x=foo().bar()`, `x` will always be set to the result of `bar()`. In this case, the result of `pack(...)` will always be `None` so `label1` will always be `None`. And obviously, `None` does not have a method named `pack_forget`.

The solution is to separate widget creation from widget layout:

```
label1 = Label(...)
label1.pack(...)
```

To address the question in the title: to remove a widget from the screen, you can use `pack_forget()` or `grid_forget()`, depending on whether you used `pack` or `grid` on that widget. Bear in mind this does *not* destroy the widget, it only removes it from view.

To completely remove the widget, call the `destroy()` method, which will delete the widget *and* remove it from view.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you have named your label `label1`, but then you do `label.pack_forget()`. it should be `label1.pack_forget()`.

secondly make sure you are doing `label1.pack_forget()` and/or `label1.destroy()` before (what i assume is) `app.mainloop()`

if you want to update the label you should use `label.config(attributes to update)`

example:

```
import tkinter

window=tkinter.Tk()

label1=tkinter.Label(window,text='this is a label!')

label1.pack()

label1.config(text='this label has been changed')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I fixed my 'label1' typo, then I tried using the label1.config() but i got an error saying that there is no attribute 'config'. I made sure that i did it before the app.mainloop()

Comment: what attributes did you put in the brackets and where exactly did you put the label1.config()?

Comment: I used label1.config(text='edited text') and I made sure that it was after the 'label1.pack()' and before the app.mainloop(). Thank you for your help and patience.